# how to optimize for concurrent requests in a data aggregator service?

Tags: java, cxf

I am building a java service that, in order to respond to user requests, requires to gather data from multiple underlying services and aggregate all the information together to response back to the user request.

To improve response time I have simple cache in the java process, to cache data retrieved from 'multiple sources' mentioned above.

**when concurrent users requests hit the service requesting for similar information I would like to avoid sending duplicate requests to underlying data sources just to warm up the cache with same information (multiple times).**

I am using java `FutureTask` to fetch data from underlying data sources and store this `Future` object in the cache. Any subsequent user request that needs this data will fetch ( or create) this Future object first and then call `get` on this  Future object to access the data. If  this data is already being retrieved as part another concurrent request all parties wanting this data will `block` automatically. This seems to work nicely but the implementation is getting a bit complicated with multiple sources and variety of cached objects.

**As I am working to refactor the code and imporve this program I feel this is a very common problem to solve and I might be re-inventing the wheel here. Is there a best practice or a framework out there that can be used as a solution here ?**

Apologies!! if the above description is vague or missing details or lack well known terms that can better describe the problem statement. I have not yet written enough java services to ask this question in fewer words.

appreciate any pointers in the right direction or info on existing frameworks that can do this job better.

thanks!!

Comment: I generally use a guava cache for such cases: https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained

Comment: probably you're interested in hazelcast https://hazelcast.com/